# Raphael js improve scale and translate performance

Tags: javascript, performance, raphael

Do you know any ways to improve raphael js scale and translate methods. It takes about 3 secs to scale 1000 objects (400 circles, 400 paths, 50 texts, 150 rectangles) and about 1.5 secs to translate those objects?

Thx a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this library: http://shapevent.com/scaleraphael/

Instead of scaling objects one by one it scales the whole canvas and preserves the original coordinate system. Works both with svg and vml.